# Opening 3rd party content in webview (android): Do I need to obtain permissions from the website owners?

Tags: android, webview

I am building an android app. One of the many features of the app require opening of 3rd party content inside a webview. Opening third party content in a webview is **not** the primary feature of the app. The PlayStore rules and regulations regarding this is as follows:

> Do not post an app where the primary functionality is to:
>
> (i) Drive affiliate traffic to a website or
>
> (ii)Provide a webview of a website not
>   owned or administered by you (unless you have permission from the
>   website owner/administrator to do so)

My question is do I still need to obtain permission from 3rd party websites to open their content in my WebView? Kindly help

Comment: If you display one webview and making money using someone's website its illegal. But if your app is like a browser you change various links from different wesbite. Its legal!

Comment: My app is huge. There is just a part of it which requires opening third party website using the webview.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it concerns Google Play Store policies and procedures, rather than programming. Please refer to: [Are developer-centric questions about application stores on topic?‍](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/272165), [Why can't I ask customer service-related questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255746)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Copyright always matter if your app is to be published for people use and you don't want any issues to get raised in future.
Copyright section are always written already within the website, or you can drop a mail and get a copyright.
If you won't take copyright then further issues can be raised by company.

Comment: What if I use a Chrome Custom Tab instead of webview? That is tailored for 3rd party websites? Do I still have to obtain permissions from the website owner?

Comment: (unless you have permission from the website owner/administrator to do so) what i exactly need to do fro permission

Comment: Go through the guidelines, they have mentioned the usage and how to ask permission.